# Expressing "almost Properness" under option type

Tags: coq, typeclass, conceptual

Suppose we have a type `A` with an equivalence relation `(===) : A -> A -> Prop` on it.

On top of that there is a function `f : A -> option A`.

It so happens that this function `f` is "almost" `Proper` with respect to `equiv`. By "almost" I mean the following:

```
Lemma almost_proper :
  forall a1 a2 b1 b2 : A,
    a1 === a2 ->
    f a1 = Some b1 -> f a2 = Some b2 ->
    b1 === b2.
```

In other words, if `f` succeeds on both inputs, the relation is preserved, but `f` might still fail on one and succeed on the other. I would like to express this concept concisely but came up with a few questions when trying to do so.

I see three solutions to the problem:

1. Leave everything as is. Do not use typeclasses, prove lemmas like the one above. This doesn't look good, because of the proliferation of preconditions like `x = Some y`, which create complications when proving lemmas.
2. It is possible to prove `Proper ((===) ==> equiv_if_Some) f` when `equiv_if_Some` is defined as follows:

   ```
   Inductive equiv_if_Some {A : Type} {EqA : relation A} `{Equivalence A EqA} : relation (option A) :=
   | equiv_Some_Some : forall a1 a2, a1 === a2 -> equiv_if_Some (Some a1) (Some a2)
   | equiv_Some_None : forall a, equiv_if_Some (Some a) None
   | equiv_None_Some : forall a, equiv_if_Some None (Some a)
   | equiv_None_None : equiv_if_Some None None.
   ```

   One problem here is that this is no longer an equivalence relation (it is not transitive).
3. It might be possible to prove `Almost_Proper ((===) ==> (===)) f` if some reasonable `Almost_Proper` class is used. I am not sure how that would work.

What would be the best way to express this concept? I am leaning toward the second one, but perhaps there are more options?

For variants 2 and 3, are there preexisting common names (and therefore possibly premade definitions) for the relations I describe? (`equiv_if_Some` and `Almost_Proper`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 if it simplifies your proofs.

The fact that it's not an equivalence relation is not a deal breaker, but it does limit the contexts in which it can be used.

`equiv_if_Some` might be nicer to define as an implication (similar to how it appears in the `almost_proper` lemma) than as an inductive type.

You may also consider using other relations (as an alternative to, or in combination with `equiv_if_Some`):

- A partial order, that can only relate `None` to `Some` but not `Some` to `None`
- A partial equivalence relation, that can only relate `Some`s.

Comment: I see how redefining `equiv_if_Some` as an implication could improve it.

Comment: That said, I don't get the suggestion to use partial relations here.
For the "in combination with" part: `equiv_if_Some` (as defined now) is neither a partial order, nor a partial equivalence.
For the "as an alternative to" part: if I try to use a partial relation, I don't see how it's possible to prove anything along the lines of `Proper`: I simply cannot compare the outputs of my function. Could you elaborate on what you mean here?

Comment: I just mean that since any single one of them doesn't have all the properties of equivalence relations, they might all be relevant together if you're going to try to do generalized rewriting. I haven't thought through how that might be the case concretely.